# Cmd+O sometimes requires two presses to work on Finder

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

I often open text files from Finder by selecting them and tapping the keyboard shortcut Cmd+O. Usually, this works in one go, but sometimes Finder will act weird and require pressing it twice to work. I've noticed this with other file types, such as PDFs, but often I find it happens with Finder and Sublime working together since that's my setup.

I recorded a video of this happening, but I can't seem to reproduce it at my will.

This has happened to me on macOS Monterey and Big Sur on silicon and x86.

Comment: This happens to me too, except with double-clicking, not Command-O. This only happens to me with folders, and only sometimes.